# Sorting objects in compareTo

Tags: java, compare

There is a model of child parent relationships in the form of a tree structure.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private UUID nextId;

    private Node parent;
    private SortedSet<Node> children = new TreeSet<>();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node node) {
         ////?????
    }

}
```

The nextId field points to the object that should be next. If the nextId field is NULL, then this object must be the last one in the list.
It turns out that it is necessary to read the nextId field for each object, find this object and display it after the existing one. After all, this field can change, so sorting in ascending order will not work and other tricks.

Is it possible to sort it at each level of the tree with such a condition in compareTo?

Comment: What do you mean by "next"?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node node) {
    if (this.nextId == null && node.nextId == null) {
        return 0; // when both elements have null as nextId
    } else if (this.nextId == null || this.id.equals(node.nextId)) {
        return 1; // when this one has null as nextId or is like the nextId of the other
    } else if (node.nextId == null || this.nextId.equals(node.id)) {
        return -1; // if the other one has null as nextId or the other one is the nextId
    }
    return this.id.compareTo(node.id); // otherwise compare the id attribute
}
```

If the `nextId` of the other one is null or it's `id` matches the `nextId` of the current object it will come after the current one.
The other way around the current object goes after when its own `nextId` is null or its `id` equals the `nextId` of the other one.

If none of the above applies I put a fallback strategy below which compares the `id`s of both objects, you can change that according to your requirements

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But not entirely reliable. The problem is that the compareTo method for sorting uses a small number of cycles. There are branches where the order is inaccurate.